# Which flutter plugin provides a chart with multipul y axis?

Tags: flutter, charts, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I wanted to have a chart which can display values of multiple parameters with different unit of measurement on the same graph. Bellow is the example of what i am looking for, where cookies and brownies have their own y-axis.

[image]

The images is taken from the bellow flutter plugin. I tried this plugin but was not able to re-create this type of multi-axis look

https://pub.dev/packages/fcharts

Comment: You can refere https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts package

Comment: I know this works really well but its paid right? for more then 5 employee organization

Comment: no this package free to used

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/license , check line number 2

Comment: I already used this package its free **syncfusion_flutter_charts: ^19.2.46** add this dependancy in your pubspec.yaml file and used it

Answer (score 0):

My approach is you can try with the google chart api. It is completely free to use from google and having great user experience also.

1. Check out the official google charts api documentation ( https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs )
2. There are lot of chart templates ( https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery )
3. All you need to know is dart-js-web interoperability ( https://dart.dev/web/js-interop )

I hope this answer helps you to find a solution to your question. Also share that how did you achieved the solution by using any alternatives, if so.